# getSelection does not return any value in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying out a simple chrome extension where I select some text and press the button and the selected term is googled.

Below is my **background.html**

```
<script>
function Req() {
var str=document.getSelection().toString(); //window.getSelection().toString() tried both
alert(str);
var Call =' http://www.google.com/search?q='+str;
alert(Call)
chrome.tabs.create({url: Call});
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="Req()" >
</body>
</html>
```

Below is my **manifest.json**

```
{
     "background_html":"background.html",
     "name": "goog app",
   "description": "googles selected term",
   "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
"popup":"background.html"
  },
"permissions": ["tabs","http://www.google.com/","https://www.google.com/"],

    "version": "1.0"
}
```

I have tried everything but the window.getSelection().toString() does not return any value.
Please help me figure out the problem.

Comment: The background page is only executed once per main process. You should swtich to Content scripts.

Comment: I tried doing it with content scripts also but can't figure out what to write in the manifest.json and even the content script does not return the value for `window.getSelection().toString()`.

Comment: `window.getSelection().toString()` inside a content script should return the currently selected text. Are you sure that some text is selected when you run the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of errors

- What is it? `"background_html":"background.html"`
- `"popup":"background.html"` - popup page does not have access to the content scripts
- `var str=document.getSelection().toString();` - you will receive selected block of the page "background.html", but not content page
- If you want to perform an action on pressing the button, see http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html#event-onClicked
- how to send message from background to content and back http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-sendRequest